# Java; Checking if 3 numbers are the same, and run code if they are

Tags: java

```
case "119":
                PotionsUpgrade();
                if(potionAttack & potionDefence & potionStrength==20){
                System.out.println("You have reached the max amount of upgrades");} else{
                cost=potionsUpgrade;
                gold=gold-cost;}
                Store(); //this is running the Store method
                break;
```

okay this is one of my cases in my game that i am building in java. I want to figure out how to check if all three of the numbers equal 20 then to tell the player that he has reached the max amount of upgrades on the potion. Else to keep buying the upgrade.

Comment: What's wrong? What doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you wondering how to write `x == 20` or are you looking for a better way to write the code?

Comment: @arthur wondering to know if you get any **error**?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think:

```
if (potionAttack & potionDefence & potionStrength==20) {
```

You have to be pretty specific with code, it's not going to interpret something that may intuitively sound logical.  It has to be specifically logical.  In this case you have three distinct logical cases you want to check.  Each one individually looks like:

```
potionAttack == 20
```

So to put all three together, each one would still look like that individually:

```
if (potionAttack == 20 && potionDefence == 20 && potionStrength == 20) {
```

(Note also the use of `&&` instead of `&`.  Different problem in the code, but not the primary one being addressed here.)

Answer (score 1):

```
`if(potionAttack == 20 & potionDefence == 20 & potionStrength == 20)`
```

The oher is the same ,but you can format it better like this

```
`if(potionAttack == 20 & potionDefence == 20 & potionStrength == 20){
     System.out.println("You have reached the max amount of upgrades");
 } 
 else{
     cost = potionsUpgrade;
     gold = gold - cost;
 }`
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using & instead of the logical and operator, &&.

Comment: Why post an answer then? Better to downvote, leave a comment, etc.

Comment: @nicomp no need to get offended. From the experience, if you make your answer better and improve it in the way that will be more informative, you would see the different result. FYI, I did not down vote you ;)

Comment: I'm very interested to learn how my critics will solve OP's problem using & instead of &&.

Comment: @KickButtowski Awesome handle.

Comment: `&` works to compare booleans. It just isn't short-circuiting. Merely switching to `&&` doesn't actually solve any problem here. The code still wouldn't compile.